# Implementing a custom interface in a COleControl using MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to implement a plugin for a customer who has an interface defined in a TLB file, which they use to get video from my system.

I've got an ActiveX control based on COleControl, which needs to implement this interface, but am having trouble figuring out how to do it correctly. I'm using DISP_FUNCTION_ID and DISP_PROPERTY_ID to hook up methods/properties to the dispinterface in the TLB, but can't figure out how to register that my class is implementing the interface so that QueryInterface will pick it up.

I'm kinda new to the whole COM thing, so please be gentle, but any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Cheers,

Callum

Answer (score 0):

TLB file is giving you the definition for Development. To register the component you actually need the COM dll. To register the DLL you need "REGSVR32" command (http://ss64.com/nt/regsvr32.html).  If you are not able to create your class as part of COM Library you can refer the example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/atl/SimpleATLCom.aspx, This will give you simple COM object.